# getvideourl from youtube for ga event label on a multiple iframes

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, google-analytics

I need to getvideourl from a multiple iframes on a page for ga event labels but it is only working with the first iframe not the second. the code i'm using is below. I've tried to use for each function but no luck.

```
  try {
      var checkYoutubeIframe = false;
      //Verify all iFrames from the page
      $("iframe").each(function () {
        //Check if you a YT iFrame
        if ($(this).attr('src').indexOf("youtube.com/embed") >= 0) {
          checkYoutubeIframe = true;
          //Add the YT ID
          if ($(this).attr('id') == undefined ||$(this).attr('id').indexOf("youTubePlayer2") == -1) {
            $(this).attr('id', 'youTubePlayer2')
          }
          //Add Enable JS API parameter
          if ($(this).attr('src').indexOf("enablejsapi=1") == -1) {
            if ($(this).attr('src').indexOf("?") >= 0) {
              var src = $(this).attr('src') + "&enablejsapi=1"
              $(this).attr('src', src)
            } else {
              var src = $(this).attr('src') + "?enablejsapi=1"
              $(this).attr('src', src)
            }
          }
        }
      })
      //Call logic if there is an iFrame on the page
      if (checkYoutubeIframe) {
        //Include YT API
        var tag = document.createElement('script');
        tag.src = "http://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
        var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
        firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);
        //Call the YT Tracker Function
        function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady(event) {
          player = new YT.Player('youTubePlayer2', {
            events: {
              'onReady': onPlayerReady,
              'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
            }
          });
        }

       function onPlayerReady(event) {}
        //Tracker
        function onPlayerStateChange(event) {
          var label = player.getVideoUrl();
             // track when user clicks to Play
          if (event.data == YT.PlayerState.PLAYING) {
            ga('send', 'event', 'Engagement', 'Play', label );
          }
          // track when user clicks to Pause
          if (event.data == YT.PlayerState.PAUSED) {
            ga('send', 'event', 'Engagement', 'Pause', label );
          }
          // track when user clicks to Pause
          if (event.data == YT.PlayerState.ENDED) {
            ga('send', 'event', 'Engagement', 'Watch to End', label );
          }
        }
      }
    } catch (e) {}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well I figured this out changed the code a bit but here is the end code and it works.

```
var tag = document.createElement('script');
tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);
var youtubePlayer1;
var youtubePlayer2;

function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
   youtubePlayer1 = new YT.Player('player1', {
    events: {
   'onReady': onPlayerReady,
   'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
  }
});
  youtubePlayer2 = new YT.Player('player2', {
    events: {
      'onReady': onPlayerReady,
      'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
    }
  });
}

function onPlayerReady(event) {}

function onPlayerStateChange(event) {
  var label = event.target.getIframe().src;
  if (event.data == YT.PlayerState.PLAYING) {
    ga('send', 'event', 'YT Videos', 'Play', label);
    pauseFlag = true;
  }
  if (event.data == YT.PlayerState.ENDED) {
    ga('send', 'event', 'YT Videos', 'Finished', label);
  } else if (event.data == YT.PlayerState.PAUSED && pauseFlag) {
    ga('send', 'event', 'YT Videos', 'Pause', label);
    pauseFlag = false;
  }
}
```